# record activations of openAI baselines implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I would like to record variables and activations of the [reference implementation for reinforcement learning provided by openAI](https://github.com/openai/baselines).
Recording weights and biases was straight forward, but I have trouble with recording the activations.
I forked [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines) and [added a commit](https://github.com/tompfeil/baselines/commit/84af37f34bbe528f8de5007fe87d4958c3450930) to record weights and biases. A [second commit](https://github.com/tompfeil/baselines/commit/a3a525f51e8d1763b8d74d2a64514de902f4d069) adds a summary operation for activations (here, activation of input only). However, the second commit results in an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1,84,84,4] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: deepq/observation = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,84,84,4], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706840/tensorflow-summery-merge-error-shape-1-784-has-negative-dimensions, but their solution does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You did not give a way to repro the error. I tried doing `python3 -m baselines.deepq.experiments.train_pong` and hit the same issue on your code. What follows is from my runs of this command on your forked code.

Your usage of `tf.summary.histogram` seems fine. The problem seem to be in another operation constructed via this stack trace:

```
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/deepq/experiments/train_pong.py", line 27, in main
  prioritized_replay=True
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/deepq/simple.py", line 178, in learn
  grad_norm_clipping=10
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/deepq/build_graph.py", line 178, in build_train
  act_f = build_act(make_obs_ph, q_func, num_actions, scope=scope, reuse=reuse)
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/deepq/build_graph.py", line 105, in build_act
  observations_ph = U.ensure_tf_input(make_obs_ph("observation"))
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/deepq/simple.py", line 170, in make_obs_ph
  return U.BatchInput(env.observation_space.shape, name=name)
File "/usr/local/google/home/iga/tinker/baselines/baselines/common/tf_util.py", line 150, in __init__
  super().__init__(tf.placeholder(dtype, [None] + list(shape), name=name))
```

There is a placeholder that deepq code creates with name `deepq/observation`.

Evaluating this placeholder causes an error because no feed is given for it during a run. The question is then is "Why adding a summary op triggers this error". The answer seems to be because we want to evaluate and write all summaries (baselines/baselines/deepq/simple.py) including the newly added summary. Evaluating the new summary requires evaluating the placeholder that causes the error.

I added some print statements to `Session.run()` method to verify that a value for `deepq/observation` is indeed not passed in feeds. It is passed for many runs, but after ~30 seconds of running on my machine, there is a call to Session.run() with a feed_dict that does not contain the value for this placeholder. The runs when it is present contain feeds for deepq/observation, deepq/update_ep, and deepq/stochastic. The run when the value is not present contains feeds for deepq_1/action, deepq_1/obs_tp1, deepq_1/weight, deepq_1/done, etc.

I am not familiar with baselines to suggest the right way of collecting the summaries you want, but hopefully this info helps.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, seems like a switch for run() may solve this issue. I'll try it out ...