# Invalid Argument Error Tensorflow Placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

n_steps = 3                       # number of time steps in RNN
n_inputs = 1                      # number of inputs received by RNN Cell at each time step
n_neurons = 10                    # number of RNN cells in hidden layer
n_outputs = 3                     # number of outputs given out by RNN
n_layers = 3                      # number of layers in network
n_epochs = 1000                   # number of epochs for RNN training 

learning_rate = 0.01              # learning rate for training step

X_train = np.array([[[1.],       
                     [2.],
                     [3.]],
                    [[4.],        # training data for input sequence
                     [5.],
                     [6.]],
                    [[7.],
                     [8.],
                     [9.]]])

y_train = np.array([[4., 5., 6.],
                    [7., 8., 9.],              # training data for output sequence
                    [10., 11., 12.]])

X_train.reshape((3, 3, 1))                     # reshape X training data

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])  # placeholder for input sequence
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs])          # placeholder for output sequence

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units = n_neurons, reuse = 
True)                                                                     # create hidden layer of 10 basic RNN cells                               




outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype = tf.float32)          # create layer using basic RNN Cell and input sequence X using dynamic RNN method (get outputs and final state)

logits = tf.layers.dense(states, n_outputs)                            # logits (and final prediction) of RNN

prediction = logits                    # final prediction of RNN

rsme = tf.square(y - prediction)       # squared deviations of predictions form targets

loss = tf.reduce_mean(rmse)            # mean of all squared deviations (cost function)

training_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 
learning_rate).minimize(loss)          # training step using Gradient Descent Optimizer


tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(n_epochs):

    sess.run(training_op , feed_dict = {X: X_train, y: y_train})       # run training operation iteratively
```

In the above code, I am trying to predict the last 3 elements of a sequence given the first 3 elements using a dynamic Recurrent Neural Network with basic RNN cells. It has an input layer with 3 neurons and a hidden layer containing 10 recursive neurons and an output layer of 3 neurons. But, it is giving an 'Invalid Argument Error', saying that I am feeding a tensor with a negative dimension of (-1, 3, 1) to a placeholder of shape (?, 3, 1). I am not able to fix this error even after plenty of desperate googling. Can someone please help me fix this error.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: (Can't reproduce) I could only get the code to run after setting `reuse=False`, and correcting a spelling error. When the code runs, I don't see any errors. Are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706840/tensorflow-summery-merge-error-shape-1-784-has-negative-dimensions

You may be getting the error because not all placeholders have been set.